# Clock Embeded in Eyelid. Choose Your Own Adventure(?)

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

I remember reading a story where one of the characters had a digital clock implanted in their eyelid.  Everywhere they looked, they could see the time.

There were a couple of problems with this.  Firstly, it was set a few minutes out – and there was no way to adjust it.  Secondly, whenever he closed his eyes to sleep, all he could see what the clock, gently glowing away!

Anyone recognise this from the (vague!) description?

I'm reasonably sure this was from a Choose Your Own Adventure style book I read in the late 1980s – early 1990s...

Comment: [This page](http://www.gamebooks.org/list_countries.php) has a list of interactive "gamebooks" by country, you can select whichever one you're from and see if any of the titles ring a bell...